# Column splitting issue Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to split data in Series format into DataFrame

```
12                                                 None
13                                 (Nokia X3, 62, 1293)
```

using command:

```
pd.DataFrame(matching_results.str.split(',')
         ,columns="Model Match_Score Id".split())
```

But, recieving just empty dataframe

```
    Model   Match_Score     Id
```

​Because "core", e.g. `matching_results.str.split(',')` returns:

```
12      NaN
13      NaN
```

`expand = True` doesn't solve it.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: What is `print (matching_results.apply(type))` ?

Comment: Sounds like `matching_results` doesn't contains what you think it does.

Comment: @jezrael 12       <class 'NoneType'>
13          <class 'tuple'>

Comment: So use `pd.DataFrame(matching_results.values.tolist()
         ,columns="Model Match_Score Id".split(), index=matching_results.index)`

Comment: @Barmar examples of data (strings 12 and 13 are represented in the question)

Comment: @jezrael Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't work `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 52686), indices imply (3, 52686)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you cannot split, because values of `Series` are `tuple`s and `None`s

It is a bit complicated, because `None`s, so first remove them by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html), use `DataFrame` contructor and last add `NaN`s by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
matching_results = pd.Series([None, ('Nokia X3', 62, 1293), None], index=[12,13,14])
print (matching_results)
12                    None
13    (Nokia X3, 62, 1293)
14                    None
dtype: object

new = matching_results.dropna()
df = pd.DataFrame(new.values.tolist(),
                  columns="Model Match_Score Id".split(),
                  index=new.index).reindex(matching_results.index)
print (df)
       Model  Match_Score      Id
12       NaN          NaN     NaN
13  Nokia X3         62.0  1293.0
14       NaN          NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!